# Can iterated arithmetical operators break closure over $\mathbb C$?

Tags: arithmetic

Multiplication is iterated addition; exponentiation is iterated multiplication, tetration is iterated exponentiation, call all of those as different grades of iterated arithmetical operators.

> Is there a known $n$-iterated arithmetical operator such that $\mathbb C$ is not closed under it?

Comment: Already raising an arbitrary complex number to an arbitrary complex power is not well-defined.

Comment: Indeed, raising a nonreal complex number to a power is well defined only when the exponent is in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Lubin, but why then it is said that the complex numbers are closed under exponentiation?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html

Comment: They’re closed all right, it’s just that the operation can not be unambiguously defined.

Comment: @Lubin, what do you mean by "unambiguously define" can you please clarify this point?

Comment: Well, there’s no way to define $i^x$ for $x\in\Bbb R$ in such a way that you always have $i^\alpha\cdot i^\beta=i^{\alpha+\beta}$.

Comment: @Lubin but there is a rule that would reduce to that when $i,\alpha, \beta$ are all in $\mathbb R^+$, so there is no real problem.

Comment: But by $i$ I meant $\sqrt{-1}$. The reason it all works as you say above is that there is a log defined for positive reals making $\log(ab)=\log a +\log b$ always. But there is no such thing for the nonzero complex numbers.

Comment: I think it's time to point out that you can get the same answer by iteration, not that they are exactly equivalent.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, what do you exactly mean? can you clarify?

Comment: addition is defined in terms of the sucessor function, and multiplication  can be but really doesn't need to be.